# In swift, some HEIC image has HEIF metadata containing CameraCalibrationData

Tags: swift, avfoundation, core-image

In swift, some HEIC image has HEIF metadata containing CameraCalibrationData.

But there is no CGImageProperties for HEIC / HEIF.

What I Want is to add CameraCalibrationData to HEIC Image.

I Found out that it's possible with 2023's Object Capture API returns HEIC Image with those.

I have tried to add metadatas, and some of TIFF, Exif metadata change worked.

But couldn't achieve with HEIF metadata.

Comment: Can you please add some code to your question, showing what you are trying to achieve? Thanks!